# requests python in Django ASGI server

Tags: python, django

I am using Django ASGI server and am sending a post request but its not responding.
Continuously displaying "sending request" in postman
My views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def test(Request):
    if Request.method == "POST":
        response=requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/token/')   
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('chat.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/token/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

This request is fine
[image]
This request is not working
[image]

Comment: I would suggest to put print in the view test() in order to verify if it gets called and one inside the 'if' clause.

Answer (score 0):

The requests.post(...) is going to the same thread that is executing your current request, so waits for execution and blocks test() from continuing and returning a response as your are here in sync functions not async.
Requests library does not support async io ... maybe look for aiohttp